# kalman filter: difference between simulation and forecasting

Tags: forecasting, simulation, kalman-filter

I know the question can sound trivial, but I can't get the difference between simulation and forecasting. If I've understood well, a forecast of $k$ periods ahead, starting from period $T$, is obtained by treating the $k$ steps as missing and proceed with conventional Kalman filtering; that is, to treat the Kalman gain as null. Now I'm thinking, Couldn't it be possible to obtain a similarly valid forecast if I make a simulation of $k$ consecutive values with the initial value *equal* to the state value in step $T$? On the whole, which are the defining differences between both methods?

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you mean by simulation. Do you mean that one would randomly sample the state at time $T+1$ (say, $x_{T+1}$) based on the state at time $T$ ($x_T$), then $x_{T+2}$ based on $x_{T+1}$, etc. until $x_{T+k}$? If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: I mean by simulation drawing samples generated by the system model and observation equations. (I sample the normal deviates of the errors of the system and observation equations.) Thereafter I proceed by predicting the next state and observation (as in filtering) using the corresponding equations. Process (sampling) is repeated at every successive step. So I guess that the answer to your question is yes.